# How to log non-python warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have .py script which starts java application from shell using `os.system`. There are always a lot of WARNING messages after starting java apperas. I want just to write them in log file without printing them in console. I dont get how to catch them... Is it possible to do using logging lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like the below

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["java", "<java args goes here>"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate() # out || err will hold the data you are looking for - you can write them to python logger
```